# How to get string value from a ValueHolder in Smalltalk?

Tags: string, user-interface, smalltalk

I have an input box in the GUI in VisionWorks. The input is treated as a `ValueHolder` that holds the string I want to traverse and whatnot, but I can't seem to get to that value. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try, `aValueHolder value`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean VisualWorks, and yes: lurker is correct `aValueHolder value` will do.

However, if your input-field has a converter attached, it may not be a ValueHolder but a TypeConverer, which has already converted the string to a number or whatever.

So what is the class of your value-thingy ("treated like" sounds like it could be something else) ?